# Roth or Traditional IRA if getting a dramatic increase in income this year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, retirement, roth-ira

So I just learned that it's not too late to fund an IRA for 2012.  With a week left and never having done this before, I now get to decide which type I want to open.

Based on my (really vague) understanding of traditional vs. Roth IRAs, I feel like a Roth IRA is the best option for me.  Here's the thing though: in 2012, my taxable income was ~25K.  In 2013 that number is going to spike up quite a bit to ~200K, and I won't be eligible to contribute to a Roth IRA anymore.

Does it still make sense for me to open a Roth IRA with the expectation of funding it for 2012 only, or is there some better alternative that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 6):

> Does it still make sense for me to open a Roth IRA with the
>   expectation of funding it for 2012 only?

Of course.

> Is there some better alternative that I'm not seeing?

Yes. You can still contribute to a non-deductible IRA for 2013, and then convert that to Roth.